# Autohotkey WinWaitActive not working with LogExpert - is there a workaround?

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

Here is my function to wait for a window to appear with a timeout of 3 seconds. If the timeout elapses, an error message is displayed.

```
WaitForWindow( title, message )
{
    WinWaitActive, %title%, ,3
    if ErrorLevel
    {
        MsgBox %message%
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

It works for all other windows, except [LogExpert](http://logexpert.codeplex.com/)

The part of the script that uses it is:

```
Run, c:\\tools\\logexpert\\logexpert.exe %MyLogFile%, max
WaitForWindow( %MyLogFile%, "No logExpert Window")
```

It doesn't matter what %MyLogFile% contains. It does not recognize the window.

This, on the other hand, works:

```
^!o::
Send ^o
if not WaitForWindow( "Open File", "No Open File Window appeared" )
{
    return
}
MsgBox "Worked"
```

Has anybody had this problem with Autohotkey and LogExpert? Is there a workaround?

Comment: You should probably ask this on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set the SetTitleMatchMode at the beginning of the script?
This will allow you to find your `%Title%` string anywhere inside the windows title of the active window.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
```

You can check the title strings with the AutoHotKey Windows Spy (Right click on AutoHotKey icon). Once the AutoHotKey Windows Spy is open, click on your target window to inspect the data from that window.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I had used Windows Spy and the text was definitely contained in the caption. Explicitly calling SetTitleMatchMode worked.

Comment: Nice to see this resolved!